# Active-active load balancers

Tags: load-balancing

I have a requirement to setup two load balancers in ACTIVE-ACTIVE mode distributing UDP traffic to back-end processing servers. 
I found a tool saru with ultramonkey but it seems project saru is not active since year 2003 and didn't find compatible packages for RHEL5.

Is there any other tools available for this kind of scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

Linux Virtual Server [does support UDP](http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/IPVS#Connection_Scheduling_Algorithms_inside_the_Kernel), not sure about HAProxy, Varnish, or Pound though.

Comment: I think LVS allows only ACTIVE-STANDBY mode, but actually here I want to run load balancers also in active-active so that resources of other server can also be utilized and in case if any server is down complete traffic will shift to other server.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following solutions might work?

- [udpbalancer](http://dev.acts.hu/udpbalancer/)
- [zenloadbalancer](http://www.zenloadbalancer.com/web/index.php?page=downloads)
- openbalance (hxxp://code.google.com/p/openbalance/) -- I'm too new to post three links...